# display format, data Format String not working for phone number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my model I want to be able to display the phone number back in the format of 111-222-1234 but can not get the desired result using dataFormatString.

```
 [Display(Name = "Home Phone")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:999-999-9999}")]
    public string homePhone { get; set; }
```

I have tried  using 0's and #'s in place of the 9's but nothing happens. I am able to change the date fine just phone number is not cooperating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:###-###-####}")]
public long Phone { get; set; }
```

Note, that in order for the formatting to be applied you would need to use the following html helper in your view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Property)
```

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Property' and no extension method 'Property' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It seems to work only if the property is of the type long - not string